# How to generate class file with dynamic property names

Tags: java

Suppose I have source java template as:

```
public class Class1 {
   private String field1;
   private int field2;
}
```

In my main method I want to generate above template java class as follows
It should generate separate `MyClass.java` file in different location

- `Class1` should be replace as `MyClass`
- `field1` should be replace as `property1`
- `field2` should be replace as `property2`

Example:

```
public class MyClass{
   private String property1;
   private int property2;
}
```

Is there any framework to achieve this? We can give dynamic names in xml file .

Comment: What would be the use case for such a functionality?

Comment: `String newFile = template.replace("Class1", className).replace("field1", propertyName1).replace("field2", propertyName2);` -> and so on...

Comment: If the goal is just code generation from XML, use JAXB or XmlBeans

Comment: I want to develop a framework ,which generate customized java classes.
This program use template java class which has dynamic fields.
This dynamic fields should replace with our given names ,Given names can be stored in xml file  or in our main method as a property

Comment: A) asking for libraries/tools is **off topic** here B) there are frameworks to generate byte code, such as [asm](https://asm.ow2.io/)

Comment: Java reflection maybe?

Comment: There are numerous template frameworks for Java that you could use for code generation.  For example, many of the frameworks listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines can be used for source code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/index.html

> The Byte Code Engineering Library (Apache Commons BCEL™) is intended to give users a convenient way to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary) Java class files (those ending with .class). Classes are represented by objects which contain all the symbolic information of the given class: methods, fields and byte code instructions, in particular.

Here https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGen you can find some examples of how to use `ClassGen`

This article also could be useful https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0414/.